# Open with explorer option doesn't show up

Tags: document-library, open-with-explorer, explorer-view

I have a library under one subsite where when I open a library in IE, the open with explorer option shows, but the same doesn't happen for another library under a different subsite. (Like it's active somewhere and somewhere it isn't). What could be the solution for this?

Comment: what's your SharePoint version? is it disabled or not shown? what's the type of the another library?

Comment: sharepoint 2013, its a simple document library.

Comment: As a workaround you can map the site / library to a network drive in Windows explorer (Rightclick the computer icon)